# Problem with connecting ESP8266 to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have:

- Arduino Uno
- [ESP8266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PI6TO8U)

Problem:
I see SoftAP and can connect to it. But I can't send AT-commands to ESP8266 from Arduino.
I use Arduino app v.1.6.5 for send command to ESP8266 via Arduino. But I don't get answer. And ESP8266 doesn't blinking.

I use this scheme:

[image: Scheme for connecting Arduino and ESP8266]

Please, help me. I'm trying to fix this is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used `SoftwareSerial` library, so you should set baud rate as 115200 for communication with esp8266. It might look like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
}
```

It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it doing the following:

Connect Arduino TX to a voltage divider (to get 3,3V) and then to TX on ESP8266
Connect Arduino RX to RX on ESP8266

It should work!.

Please read the information on this link 
http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf

Comment: From memory the ESP8266 can pull more current than the Arduino can supply so you need a separate 3.3V supply.
You also need 3.3V/5V logic level shifters on ALL you connections between the Arduino and the ESP, because the ESP of the different in logic levels.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to add another power supply, which will give to the wifi module not just the correct voltage (3v) but the mA that it need.  / other thing you may need to do is connect the ground of Arduino to Ground of the power supply. For me works good.

the connections would be like this

1. esp TX     > arduino dpin 10
2. esp RX     > arduino dpin 11
3. esp CH     > to VCC 3V
4. esp RST    > to pushbutton connected to gnd
5. esp GpIO 0 > none
6. esp GpIO 2 > none
7. esp VCC > power supply 3v
8. esp GND > power supply gnd